# Catching exceptions in Spring Web Flux

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-webflux

I have the following class for invoking a time-consuming operation via web-service:

```
@Service
public class InferenceService {

    @Autowired
    private final WebClient inferenceClient;

    public ByteArrayResource invoke(FileSystemResource resource) throws HttpException {
        Mono<ByteArrayResource> mono = inferenceClient
                .post()
                .uri(INFERENCE_URI)
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/zip"))
                .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(resource))
                .accept()
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(ByteArrayResource.class);

        ByteArrayResource zip = mono.block();
        return zip;
    }
}
```

If an exception occurs during web service invocation, like UnknownHostException, it is wrapped in a ReactiveException. I want my class to catch the original exception and rethrow it as a HttpException, so that I'm able to log it, handle by Spring exception handler, return 500 status from my controller and not to have a difficult to read stacktrace with suppressed exceptions in my log. I wrote something like this:

```
@Service
public class InferenceService {

    @Autowired
    private final WebClient inferenceClient;

    public ByteArrayResource invoke(FileSystemResource resource) throws HttpException {
        Mono<ByteArrayResource> mono = inferenceClient
                .post()
                .uri(INFERENCE_URI)
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/zip"))
                .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(resource))
                .accept()
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, this::getStatus500Error)
                .bodyToMono(ByteArrayResource.class);

        try {
            ByteArrayResource zip = mono.block();
            return zip;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw extractFromReactiveException(e);
        }
    }

    private Mono<? extends Throwable> getStatus500Error(ClientResponse clientResponse) {
        return Mono.error(new InternalServerError(getStatusErrorMsg(clientResponse)));
    }

    private HttpException extractFromReactiveException(RuntimeException e) {
        if (e.getCause() instanceof HttpException) {
            return (HttpException) e.getCause();
        } else {
            return new InternalServerError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But I feel that either there's a better way, or what i'm trying to achieve is wrong. What's the proper way?

Comment: Hey Andrey, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You should never use block. The intent of reactor is to handle everything inside the chain. So your method should return an Mono instead of the object itself.

If you want to change the exception, you should use         .onErrorMap(throwable -> extractFromReactiveException(throwable));
after bodyToMono.

And make the extract method return a HttpException instead of a Mono.

Here is the documentation, look for the onErrorMap method and its overloads.
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/

Feel free to ask if you have any further doubts!